# Fetch Facebook comments from external website

Tags: comments, facebook-comments

According to this [post](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/490/), we could fetch Facebook comments from any page that has that plugin.

So from this URL:

```
http://www.espncricinfo.com/india/content/story/638252.html
```

I tried to fetch comments using:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/?ids=http://www.espncricinfo.com/india/content/story/638252.html
```

But, I didnt get the comments. Instead, I'm getting only the share count:

```
{
   "http://www.espncricinfo.com/india/content/story/638252.html": {
      "id": "http://www.espncricinfo.com/india/content/story/638252.html",
      "shares": 81
   }
}
```

When I try:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/comments/?ids=http://www.espncricinfo.com/india/content/story/638252.html
```

I get the following empty set:

```
{
   "http://www.espncricinfo.com/india/content/story/638252.html": {
      "comments": {
         "data": [

         ]
      }
   }
}
```

How to fetch the comments?

Comment: What happens when you append &fields=comments to your query?

Comment: @JayNCoke No change in output

Answer (score 0):

use the following url  **https://graph.facebook.com/comments/?ids=http://www.espncricinfo.com/india/content/story/638252.html** instead of https://graph.facebook.com/?ids=http://www.espncricinfo.com/india/content/story/638252.html

Comment: Still no luck. Updated my question.